# apt install return /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 but i'm on x86_64 machine

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm running on x86_64 machine

```
uname -a
```

return

```
5.4.0-135-generic #152~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 29 08:23:49 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

when I'm using apt or apt-get i get error message of:

input:

```
sudo apt install tree
```

output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
tree is already the newest version (1.7.0-5).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-spiceclientglib-2.0 gir1.2-spiceclientgtk-3.0 gnome-online-accounts linux-headers-5.4.0-131-generic linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-131 linux-image-5.4.0-131-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-131-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-131-generic python3-macaroonbakery python3-nacl python3-protobuf python3-pymacaroons python3-rfc3339 python3-tz ubuntu-system-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  multiboot-doc grub-emu xorriso desktop-base
The following packages will be upgraded:
  grub-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 42 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,810 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 246727 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../grub-common_2.02-2ubuntu8.25_amd64.deb ...
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: initscript grub-common, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: old grub-common package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: initscript grub-common, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/grub-common_2.02-2ubuntu8.25_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new grub-common package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: initscript grub-common, action "start" failed.
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed grub-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/grub-common_2.02-2ubuntu8.25_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The sources are

input:

```
> cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

output:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

also

```
cat cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-bionic.list
```

output:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic main
```

I tried to reinstall apt and dpkg, but i didn't helped
i cant understand why x68_64 will need ld-linux-armhf.so.3

Comment: done, full output

Comment: The list of packages to be removed suggests severe errors in your sources exist. Please add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` to your question.

Comment: @OrganicMarble done

Comment: Do you perhaps have an ARM version of dpkg installed somewhere early in sudo's `secure_path`? What does `sudo bash -c 'type -a dpkg'` say? How about `sudo bash -c 'ldd $(command -v dpkg)'` ?

Comment: @steeldriver i  guess i have in some way  
"sudo bash -c 'ldd $(command -v dpkg)'
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc4f07000)
 libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f70c4bf7000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f70c4806000)
 libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f70c4595000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f70c4391000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f70c527c000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f70c4172000)"

Comment: @steeldriver  and the sudo bash -c 'type -a dpkg' is dpkg is /usr/bin/dpkg

Comment: Those would be easier to read as edits rather than comments - but I don't see anything ARM related there. Must be some other issue.

Comment: It could be something injected in shell/bash profile/rc, because it seems to repeat multiple times for same step. Have you @yntnm modified it or installed manually new a tool lately?

Comment: ... since `invoke-rc.d` is a POSIX shell script (`/bin/sh`) that invokes another POSIX shell script (`/etc/init.d/grub-common`) I wonder if it is `/bin/sh` that is messed up? Either symlinked to something other than `/bin/dash` or `/bin/dash` itself is broken?

Comment: @steeldriver yes "dpkg is /usr/bin/dpkg"

Comment: @user.dz i do a lot of cross compile to arm, so i do lot of change, i dont know what broke what and when...

Comment: @yntnm I'm not so interested in dpgk itself (I think we've pretty much ruled that out) - can you please check what /bin/sh resolves to (e.g. `realpath /bin/sh`) and verify that *it* works correctly

Comment: realpath /bin/sh points to /bin/dash, and when i'm run it looks good...